Satisfiable and Unsatisfiable k-SAT formulae that violate the same number of constraints on many inputs
I want to, for arbitrary $k$ and $n$, construct two $k$-SAT formulae, one satisfiable ($f$) and one unsatisfiable ($g$), such that there are $\Omega(2^{\alpha n})$ inputs $x$ where $f(x)=g(x)+c$ for any constant $c$. Here $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ is the number of clauses in $f$ or $g$ satisfied by $x$. For a simple and dumb example if $k=n=2$:
f = $(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \neg x_2) \land (\neg x_1 \lor x_2) \land ( x_1 \lor x_2)$,
g= $(x_1 \lor x_2) \land (x_1 \lor \neg x_2) \land (\neg x_1 \lor x_2) \land (\neg x_1 \lor \neg x_2)$,
Then
$f(00)=2, f(01)=3, f(10)=3, f(11)=4$,
$g(00)=3, g(01)=3, g(10)=3, g(11)=3$,
so with $c=0$ there are two inputs such that $f(x)=g(x)+c$.
When $k=n$ a similar construction gives $2^k-2=\Theta(2^n)$ inputs that agree, however, there are now an exponential number of clauses.
I am wondering if there is a smarter construction possible, where the number of clauses is polynomial in $n$ while the number of inputs that agree is exponential, or if there is some proof that this may never be the case?

The context for the question is to find a worst-case example in order to prove an interesting lower bound on the quantum query complexity of deciding k-SAT problems with access to an oracle in the form of equation 2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.4028

Normally we would encourage you to provide the motivation for this question (e.g., why should we care what the answer is?), and/or the context in which you encountered it / the context in which it arose.

Understood - just added motivation

Let $f$ be any satisfiable $k$-CNF formula on $n$ variables, and define $g$ by
$$g = f \land \text{True} \land \text{True} \land \dots \land \text{True} \land \text{False}.$$
If there are $c$ copies of $\text{True}$, then $f,g$ satisfy your conditions for all $x$, and thus there are $\Omega(2^{\alpha n})$ such inputs.

If you don't want to allow $\text{False}$, replace $\dots \land \text{False}$ by $\dots \land (x_1) \land (\neg x_1)$ (two separate clauses), and get rid of one of the $\text{True}$'s.  Then $f,g$ still satisfy your conditions.

If you don't want to allow repeated clauses, you can tweak this to meet that constraint as well:
Choose $\beta$ such that ${2\beta \choose \beta} \ge c$, and replace each $\text{True}$ in the definition of $g$ above by a different disjunction of $\beta$ of the last $2\beta$ variables.  Then $f(x)=g(x) + c$ for all inputs $x$ such that at least $\beta+1$ of the last $2\beta$ variables are True.  There are $2^{n-1}$ such inputs (since, by symmetry, half of all assignments to the last $2\beta$ variables satisfy the condition), and this is $\Omega(2^{\alpha n})$.

One of the conditions, though is that f must be satisfiable and g must be unsatisfiable. In these constructs, either both or neither are satisfiable

@hahmez, See revised answer.

thank you! I will see if this method works for my proof construction
